# you need one to create a basic framework with ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, frameworks

I am curious how it works inside a web framework. how to develop with Ruby, I wonder what is the basic need to develop a web framework with ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to respond to HTTP requests.

A 70-line, simplistic (but threaded, with some content type handling) server:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/10/14/474841.aspx

Everything else is sugar. The ability to easily map URLs to handlers is an implementation detail. Getting data to the view layer (assuming the view layer isn't just Ruby, a la Markaby) is an implementation detail.

Everything you see in Rails, Sinatra, etc. are implementation details designed specifically to make developing apps easier, normalized, consistent, etc.